# Sum array elements in two dimensional array with duplicate element value

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have a multi array that has some duplicated values that are same by payment_name ( payment_name is an element )
I want to sum quantity of each array that has same payment_name and display the amount as one. For now the sum comes as array of all amounts. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

var_export($num) results looks like this

```
array( 
    'items' => array ( 
        '2020-08-04' => array ( 
            0 => array ( 
                0 => array ( 
                    'payment_name' =>'Cash',
                    'amount_paid' => array (
                        0 => '0', 
                    ),
                ), 
            ), 
            1 => 0, 
        ),
        '2020-08-05' => array ( 
            0 => array( 
                0 => array ( 
                    'payment_name' => 'Cash', 
                    'amount_paid' => array ( 
                            0 => '0', 
                            1 => '0', 
                            2 => '165', 
                    ), 
                ),
                1 => array ( 
                    'payment_name' => 'Mpesa', 
                    'amount_paid' => array ( 
                            0 => '0', 
                            1 => '0',
                            2 => '165', 
                    ), 
                ), 
            ), 
            1 => 165, 
        ),
```

My expected array should be like this, the amount paid should be the total, not an array of all amounts:

```
    "2020-08-05" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "payment_name" => "Cash"
          "amount_paid" => "0"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "payment_name" => "Mpesa"
          "amount_paid" =>  "165"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => 165
    ]
```

My code is as below

```
$requests = $builder->get()->groupBy('date');

$num = $requests->map(function ($row) {

    $result = array();

    $ttl = $row->sum('amount_paid');

    $row = $row->toArray();

    $names = array_column($row, 'payment_name');
    $amount = array_column($row, 'amount_paid');

    $unique_modes = array_unique($names);

    foreach ($unique_modes as $name) {
        $this_keys = array_keys($names, $name);
        $qty = array_sum((array_intersect_key($amount, array_combine($this_keys, $this_keys))));
        $result[] = array("payment_name"=>$name, "amount_paid"=>$amount);
    }
    
    return [$result, $ttl ];
});

return $num;
```

Comment: If you are coding in PHP, please show us array dumps using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` or even `var_export()` and not the browsers debugger output

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, im showing num

Comment: @RiggsFolly the first

Comment: Showing us the array dump using `var_export()` even makes it easy for us to grab the array and play with it to test a possible answer !!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I post the whole result here? its quite long

Comment: No, but a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is useful

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay, tried editing the question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem using the code below:

```
$num = $requests->map(function ($row) {

            $result = array();

            $ttl = $row->sum('amount_paid');

            $row = $row->toArray();

            $final_array = [];

            foreach($row as $arr){
            $final_array[$arr['payment_name']]['payment_name'] = $arr['payment_name'];
            $final_array[$arr['payment_name']]['amount_paid'] = (isset($final_array[$arr['payment_name']]['amount_paid']))? $final_array[$arr['payment_name']]['amount_paid']+$arr['amount_paid'] : $arr['amount_paid'];    
            }
            $final_array = array_values($final_array);

            return [$final_array, $ttl];

        });
```